# Airflow: Plugins broken with 1.10.14 & Python 3.8

Tags: python, airflow

Using / installing any Plugins with Apache Airflow 1.10.14 breaks Airflow when using Python 3.8.

Example: Run

```
pip install airflow-exporter==1.3.2
```

And then try to run Airflow Webserver and Scheduler.

You will see the following Error:

```
[2020-12-11 14:12:29,757] {plugins_manager.py:159} ERROR - Failed to import plugin AirflowPrometheus                                                                            │
│ Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              │
│   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/plugins_manager.py", line 150, in load_entrypoint_plugins                                                      │
│     plugin_obj.__usable_import_name = entry_point.module                                                                                                                        │
│ AttributeError: 'EntryPoint' object has no attribute 'module'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13019#issuecomment-743255624

This is a bug in Airflow 1.10.14 and is fixed by installing `importlib-metadata` in Python 3.8 environment:

```
pip install 'importlib-metadata~=2.0'
```

The fix for it (https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/e75deee11ab8ed626979f1fe3927049a200ab676) is merged and will be available in Airflow 1.10.15 or Airflow 2.0 whichever is first.